# Not able to see 3d map in rviz

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i want to make 3d map using UTM-30LX.  I created 2d map. Then I write tf_broadcaster to provide transform between /world and /laser frame when hokuyo is moving in upward direction.  Not able to see 3d map in rviz. The tf_broadcaster.cpp is given below.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf_broadcaster");
  
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  ros::Rate rate(30.0);
  static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
  tf::Transform transform;

while(ros::ok()) {
  transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) );
  tf::Quaternion q;
  q.setRPY(0, 0, 0);
  transform.setRotation(q);
  br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "world", "laser"));
  rate.sleep();
  ros::spinOnce();
}

  return 0;
};
```

In rviz "no /world frame exist" error is coming. Can anybody tell me where i am wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224946/not-able-to-see-3d-map-in-rviz/) by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-26**:
Just a guess: what are you using to create the map? Can you see the Scan?
Maybe the frame_id of whatever you use to create the map expects the `/` in front of `world` which you are not publishing. It should be removed then.

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-27**:
i am using hector_mapping to create a map with that i am able to see 2d map in rviz.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-28**:
alright, so you have a 2D map. But what about 3D? This is what is not working...
Check the `frame_id`s there.

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-31**:
According to me frame id should be world. Do you think this is the right way to create a 3d map?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-01**:
Are you using any program that actually provides some 3D mapping algorithm? If yes, which one? If no, there will be no 3D map...

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-02-01**:
Actually i don't know any algorithm for generating 3d map. I thought by providing transform between world and laser will create 3d map. Do you know any algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a 3D mapping algorithm to build and see a 3D map. There are several available, e.g. [`octomap_mapping`](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_mapping) (which relies on another localization source, i.e. this is not a SLAM algorithm).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0